# Why does my 19 month old son refuse to eat solids?

Tags: eating, solids

My 19 month old son refuses to eat solid food. Every time I have tried giving him finger food, as soon as he puts it in his mouth he will throw it up.

The only way I can get my son to eat is to blend his food, then he will eat it - but he will refuse any solids lumps and throw up.

What can I do to help him eat solid foods?

Comment: Kealeigh, welcome to the site.  I made some edits to clean up the grammar, and I also added an actual question - if this isn't what you're asking, please clarify.  But be aware, we're not able to answer medical questions, so if the question is "should I take my child to the doctor", the answer is "yes", but not because of anything we're able to say about your situation - that's the answer any time you have to ask.  :)

Comment: A doctor should be your first step, would be bad to suggest something thinking the issue is one thing and then have the issue be something else and harm the child with one of the many suggestions I have.

Comment: What kind of solid foods have you offered? Please give some specific examples.

Comment: Does your child make any attempt to chew their food if you present them with something that can't be swallowed directly?

Comment: When you say 'throw up', do you mean vomiting, or willfully spitting it out?

Answer (score 2):

Throwing up when introduced to different textures might be a sign of Sensory Food Aversion/Sensory Processing Disorder (please refer, for example, to this article on [NYT](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/04/17/parenting/sensory-processing-disorder-kids.html), or this one on [WebMD](https://www.webmd.com/children/sensory-processing-disorder)).

My now 4-year-old child used to live exclusively on a liquid diet since they were 12 months old. They have been recently diagnosed with SPD and life has started to improve since we started treatment.

If you have tried other tips and tricks for picky eaters and none of them worked, I would suggest you look into this.

Here is a [useful blog entry](https://www.meganboitano.com/blog/sensory-food-aversion-refusing-textures) on the issue:

> **What is a Sensory Food Aversion?**
> When eating, you are exposed to a significant number of sensory inputs. From visual appearance of food, smell, temperature, taste and texture, eating is a demanding experience from a sensory perspective.  Some children are over (or under) responsive to the sensory elements of food and eating. This can mean gagging at the sight or smell of certain foods.  It can also be vomiting or spitting food out.  Sensory food aversion can occur for many reasons, but often it is the result of difficulty processing the sensory aspects of eating. Children with an aversion are often labeled as picky or selective eaters.

Comment: Why the use of *it*? If you want to be gender neutral,  *they* Is better, "it" is for objects.

Comment: @eipi please *help* by suggesting an edit, not everyone is a native speaker and for example in my native language the equivalent of “it” would be perfectly fine, even the best choice in many cases.